# is there a way to prevent my component package from installing styled-component in it's directory in node modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, styled-components, tsc

i have a custom ui library made with react and styled components, i've specified in the library's package.json to use my main apps styled-components

```json
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "nuka-carousel": "6.0.3",
    "styled-components": "6.0.8"
  },
```

but when i include the library in my app and run yarn install i noticed that it's installed in the library's node_module[image]

as a result the component breaks when trying to access my apps theme

```bash
- error Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'h1')
    at /Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/ui-kit/lib/components/H1/styled/H1.js:16:36
    at ke (/Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/ui-kit/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1:17838)
    at e.generateAndInjectStyles (/Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/ui-kit/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1:19353)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/ui-kit/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1:21658
    at /Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/ui-kit/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1:21771
    at I (/Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/ui-kit/node_modules/styled-components/dist/styled-components.cjs.js:1:21998)
    at renderWithHooks (/Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderForwardRef (/Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5842:18)
    at renderElement (/Users/user/Desktop/code/appclient/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development
```

if i delete the `styled-components` inside the library inside `node_modules`

[image]

the app starts working as expected as it's using the `styled-components` of my main app

[image]

Let me know if there's something i'm missing that could be causing the issue. I can provide more details if necessary as well. Thanks!

Edit:
Adding package json of library and my main app as requested

my library

```json
{
  "name": "uikit",
  "version": "1.16.0",
  "description": "A collection of components",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "resolutions": {
    "@storybook/react-docgen-typescript-plugin": "1.0.6--canary.9.cd77847.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "jackspeak": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "compile:clean": "rimraf lib coverage",
    "compile": "tsc -m es6 --outDir lib-",
    "lint": "yarn run lint:eslint && yarn run lint:stylelint",
    "test:full": "yarn lint && yarn test:unit",
    "test:unit": "yarn jest",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "release": "yarn compile:clean && yarn compile",
    "release:major": "yarn release && standard-version --release-as major",
    "release:minor": "yarn release && standard-version --release-as minor",
    "release:patch": "yarn release && standard-version --release-as patch",
    "release:alpha": "yarn release && standard-version --prerelease alpha",
    "start": "yarn storybook",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "components",
    "icons"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.22.10",
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.1.3",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/addons": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/source-loader": "^7.4.6",
    "@storybook/theming": "^7.4.6",
    "@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js": "^0.38.0",
    "@types/body-scroll-lock": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.195",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.6",
    "@types/react-motion": "^0.0.35",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "@types/shortid": "^0.0.30",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.45.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.45.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-async": "^1.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.14",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "postcss-syntax": "^0.36.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "standard-version": "^9.5.0",
    "storybook": "^7.4.6",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "stylelint": "^14.9.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^8.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^29.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.9.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "downshift": "^6.1.12",
    "file-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "fuzzysort": "^2.0.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "jest-jasmine2": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.1.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.8.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "luxon": "^3.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "nuka-carousel": "6.0.3",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.0.2",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.0.2",
    "react-moment-proptypes": "^1.8.1",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "react-truncate-markup": "^5.1.2",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "styled-components": "6.0.8",
    "stylis": "^4.0.0",
    "uniqid": "^5.4.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "nuka-carousel": "6.0.3",
    "styled-components": "6.0.8"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "jsx",
      "js",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testRunner": "jest-jasmine2",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/lib/"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "rpmbuild"
    ],
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>",
      "./src"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>",
      "./src"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-addons-test-utils/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/fbjs",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/core-js",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/jasmine-reporters"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn test"
    }
  }
}
```

my main app

```
{
  "name": "appclient",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean:next": "node clean_next.js",
    "check:connection": "node check_connection.js",
    "clean:check:connection": "yarn run clean:next && yarn run check:connection",
    "dev": "yarn run clean:check:connection && NODE_ENV=development env-cmd next -p 3020",
    "dev:otel": "OTEL_ENADLED='true' yarn run dev",
    "build": "IS_BUILDING='true' NODE_ENV=production next build",
    "start": "IS_BUILDING='false' next start",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage --testPathIgnorePatterns cypress/**",
    "load_test": "siege -c10 -i -t30M -f ./tests/load_test_locations.txt",
    "lint": "yarn run eslint && yarn run stylelint",
    "eslint": "$(yarn bin)/eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src/**",
    "stylelint": "$(yarn bin)/stylelint src/**",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "stylelint"
    ]
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.8.5",
    "@boiseitguru/cookie-cutter": "^0.2.1",
    "@cloudnative/health": "^2.1.2",
    "@cloudnative/health-connect": "^2.1.0",
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^4.50.1",
    "@marvelapp/react-ab-test": "^3.1.0",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http": "^0.44.0",
    "@opentelemetry/resources": "^1.17.1",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-node": "^0.44.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base": "^1.17.1",
    "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "^1.17.1",
    "@optimizely/optimizely-sdk": "^4.10.0",
    "@researchgate/react-intersection-observer": "^1.3.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.3.1",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^2.1.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.1",
    "@types/actioncable": "^5.2.9",
    "actioncable": "^5.2.8",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
    "apollo-link-rest": "^0.9.0",
    "array-move": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
    "cypress-wait-until": "^2.0.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.3.1",
    "device": "^0.3.11",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "uikit": "1.16.1",  // my custom package
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "graphql-ruby-client": "^1.11.9",
    "html-react-parser": "^4.2.2",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.47",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lru-cache": "^10.0.1",
    "luxon": "^3.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "next-api-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "next-useragent": "^2.8.0",
    "nuka-carousel": "^5.5.1",
    "pino": "^8.16.0",
    "pluralize": "^8.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "qs": "^6.11.2",
    "query-string": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cropper": "^2.3.3",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-inlinesvg": "^4.0.5",
    "react-marquee-slider": "^1.1.5",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scroll-to-component-ssr": "^1.0.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "react-spring": "^9.7.3",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^5.21.5",
    "react-waypoint": "^10.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.6",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.9",
    "stylis": "^4.0.0",
    "use-clipboard-copy": "^0.2.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "@percy/cli": "^1.27.3",
    "@percy/cypress": "^3.1.2",
    "@stylelint/postcss-css-in-js": "^0.38.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.199",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.22.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "cypress": "^13.3.1",
    "cypress-plugin-tab": "^1.0.5",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.19",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.15.1",
    "eslint-plugin-es": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-optimize-regex": "^1.2.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.5.2",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.5.2",
    "jest-cli": "^29.6.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.4",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^14.0.1",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.3",
    "mochawesome-merge": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-styled": "^0.34.0",
    "postcss-styled-syntax": "^0.5.0",
    "postcss-syntax": "^0.36.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^15.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint": "^15.10.3",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^13.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "5.88.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "jsx",
      "js",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": [
        "babel-jest",
        {
          "presets": [
            "next/babel"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(decode-uri-component|filter-obj|split-on-first|query-string)/)"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "src",
      "."
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupTests.js",
      "jest-canvas-mock"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put all package.json file for me?

Comment: @PooriaSet sure thing. just updated the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installed version of styled-components in the main app is different from the version that exists in the custom library.

Just remove `styled-component` from custom library dependencies and use a lenient version of `styled-component` in custom library `peerDependencies` like as ^6.0.0 as follows:

```json
  "peerDependencies": {
    "styled-components": "^6.0.0"
  }
```

If styled-component is used in your custom library, just add it to `devDependencies` not `dependencies`.

Based on `npm` blog and [this post](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies):

> peer dependency requirements, unlike those for regular dependencies, should be lenient. You should not lock your peer dependencies down to specific patch versions. It would be really annoying if one Chai plugin peer-depended on Chai 1.4.1, while another depended on Chai 1.5.0, simply because the authors were lazy and didn't spend the time figuring out the actual minimum version of Chai they are compatible with.

If you want your package to use the same `styled-component` as the main app, find a lower version of styled-component that is compatible with your app and use a lenient requirement in `peerDependencies` so that styled-component does not get placed in your custom library folder unnecessarily

Comment: just updated the question and added the package.json of both apps

Comment: @rogelio I edited my answer and recommended a correct `peerDependencies` for styled-component, don't forget to remove styled-component from dependencies.

Comment: it works! though it's a bit weird to always add it back to the dependencies every time i want to do development on the library, i'm wondering if there's another way around this.

Comment: I would recommend you studying Peer Dependencies from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies). The package (your custom library) must either be in dependencies or in peerDependencies or devDependencies. place in both is wrong!

You should always add it to `devDependencies` for development purposes, and there is no need to move it back to deps every time you want to develop.